# Highcharts series name with '<' not rendered in tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I have a situation where my series name needs to be something like '< 18.5'. It shows on the legend but the tooltip shows a blank for this. How can I overcome this? I am using the latest version 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the value like `<` is `&lt;`.

See: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#use

Code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['&lt;Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/hHkAm/